# paramValues not working in JSTL and throwing an exception?

Tags: jstl

THis is my first page

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
     </head>
     <body>
        <form action="newjstl.jsp" method="post">  
     FirstName:<input type="text" name="fname"/><br/>  
     LastName:<input type="text" name="lname"/><br/>  
     <input type="submit" value="submit"/>  
     </form>  
      </body>
      </html>
```

The second page is

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  

    <c:forEach var='value' items='${paramValues}'>
          First Name:<c:out value="${value.fname}"></c:out><br/>  
          Last Name:<c:out value="${value.lname}"></c:out>  
        </c:forEach>
```

**It is throwing an exception** org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.util.HashMap$Entry' does not have the property 'fname'.
I don't know why it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp71044.

`paramValues` is the map of parameters. It maps parameter names (the keys of the map) to their values (array of String).

You're iterating over this map. The forEach loop thus iterates over the entries of the map, which are of type `Map.Entry<String, String[]>`. And Map.Entry doesn't have any `getFname()` method.

What you actually want is

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  

First Name:<c:out value="${param.fname}" /><br/>  
Last Name:<c:out value="${param.lname}" />
```

There's no reason to loop, and you simply want to get the single value of a given parameter. That'w what `param` is for.

Comment: I know that I have done this using param.fname but now I want to do this using paramValues so if can help me acheiving the same output using paramValues I would be much greatful.

Comment: That's basically like wanting to hit a nail with a screwdriver. But `paramValues.fname[0]` should work.

Comment: Then try paramValues['fname'][0]. But why in hell would you want to use that rather than param.fname?

Comment: As its an Map.Entry, maybe value.getValue().fname works?

Comment: hmm, I am not fluent in JSP, just thought it might work, another option to try would be value.value.fname

Answer (score 1):

JB Nizet has it correctly.

Assume that 'fname' was set to "George", and 'lname' was set to "Smith" in 'first page'.

'paramValues' is a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), so when you use it in 'forEach', what you're getting in 'value' is a [Map.Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html), and Map.Entry doesn't have a 'fname' field, so there's no 'getFname' method for JSP to call.

If you insist, 'value' can be used as '${value.key}' and '${value.value}', but that will get you the pairs :

```
'fname', "George"
'lname', "Smith"
```

respectively.  I doubt that's what you want.  The only reason to use a 'forEach' would be if you were expecting multiple answers and needed to iterate through all of them.  That's not what's been given as the example.

The following was copied from [Implicit Objects](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30946&seqNum=7), and shows pretty much what I suggest above.

```
  <%-- For every String[] item of paramValues... --%>
  <c:forEach var='parameter' items='${paramValues}'> 
     <ul>
        <%-- Show the key, which is the request parameter
             name --%>
        <li><b><c:out value='${parameter.key}'/></b>:</li>

        <%-- Iterate over the values -- a String[] -- 
             associated with this request parameter --%>
        <c:forEach var='value' items='${parameter.value}'>
           <%-- Show the String value --%>
           <c:out value='${value}'/>   
        </c:forEach>
     </ul>
  </c:forEach>
```

Comment: TruePS asked me to look at this one.

Comment: I understand completely what you are saying but I just wanted to get an example of paramvalues.There should be some way to get George Smith using paramvalues.

Comment: @TruePS Well, since I don't have a JSP site handy to test with, I don't know if this will work, but you might try using 'forEach' on the result of ${paramValues.values}.  The 'values' method of HashMap returns a collection, so 'forEach' should be happy with it.  The thing is, I'm not sure if JSP is going to call the 'values' method of HashMap, or go looking for a 'getValues' method.  If the latter, this won't work.  In addition, there's no guarantee of the order you'd get the values in.  It could as easily be Smith George, as George Smith.

Comment: Can't help then.  Sorry!

Comment: It's alright man just I last help I searched for many examples of paramValues but couldn't find any example worthy enough.If you could please find me any simple example of 10-20 lines regarding using paramvalues then I would be more than happy to close this question and mark your answer as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

To pass parameters to a jsp jstl:

```
/* JSP PARENT */

<jsp:include page="../../templates/options.jsp">                    
    <jsp:param name="action" value="${myValue}"/>       
</jsp:include>


/* JSP CHILD (options.jsp)*/

<div id="optionButtons left">       
    <span>${param.action}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the fields in your form aren't named the same, you can't use 'forEach' tag. I think this will work!

```
First Name:${param.fname}
Last Name:${param.lname}
```