# Can't resolve java.io.EOFException?

Tags: java, file-io

This is my first file

```
   public class ObjectStream 
     {
       public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
     {
     java.io.File f=new java.io.File("D:Employee.outt") ;  
      Employee e=new Employee("John");
      Employee e1=new Employee("Mary");
         Employee e2=new Employee("Christian");
       OutputStream os=new java.io.FileOutputStream(f);

       java.io.ObjectOutputStream oos=  new ObjectOutputStream(os);
      oos.writeObject(e);
       oos.writeObject(e1);
         oos.writeObject(e2);
      }
      }
```

This is my second file

```
    public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable
    {
     private static int count=100;
    private int eid;
     private String ename;

     public Employee()
    {
     count++;
     this.eid=count;        
    }

    public Employee(String ename)
   {
    this();
    this.ename=ename;        
    }

    public static int getCount() {
       return count;
     }

    public static void setCount(int count) {
      Employee.count = count;
     }

     public int getEid() {
      return eid;
      }

    public void setEid(int eid) {
      this.eid = eid;
    }

    public String getEname() {
      return ename;
     }

     public void setEname(String ename) {
         this.ename = ename;
   }

   }
```

This is my third file

```
      public class MainClass
    {
         public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException,        IOException, ClassNotFoundException
       {
        File f=new File("D:Employee.outt");
       byte data[]=new byte[(int)f.length()];
    InputStream is=new java.io.FileInputStream(f);
      java.io.ObjectInputStream ois=new java.io.ObjectInputStream(is);
    Object o=ois.readObject();



    while(o!=null)
         {
   Employee e=(Employee)o;
   System.out.println(e.getEid());
   System.out.println(e.getEname());
     o=ois.readObject();
       }


    ois.close();
    is.close();
     }
     }
```

I am trying to read objects stored in Employee.outt in via this third file but it is reading all the objects but at the end throwing

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException.

I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Have you verified file path & name? Shouldn't it be `D:\\Employee.outt` ?

Comment: @Shishir Yes I have It is reading file,there is no problem in reading file but at the end of file it is giving EOF exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EOFException when reading files with ObjectInputStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684072/eofexception-when-reading-files-with-objectinputstream)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(o!=null)
```

This isn't a valid way to read an `ObjectInputStream.` The `readObject()` method only returns a null if you wrote a null. At end of stream it throws, guess what, an `EOFException,` so the correct way to read the stream is to loop calling `readObject() until you catch that exception, then break and close the stream.

> at the end of file it is giving EOF exception

That's exactly what `EOFException` means.

Comment: but my friend run the same program by doing the same thing.I just don't wanna catch the exception I just wanna know when object reaches End of stream and close my loop just like in Filereader when EOF has reached it returns -1 and we close our loop.

Comment: You can also first send the length of how many objects will be transferred, then you can stop reading based on that.

Comment: You don't have any choice. That's how the API works. It throws `EOFException:` you have to catch it. And you can't rely on information in the file as suggested by @centic: premature end of file can still happen in the real world, and you still have to deal with it correctly.

Comment: @centic How can I know the length of objects if I am reading say a random file.

Comment: @EJP Can you explain "premature end of file can still happen in the real world, and you still have to deal with it correctly".How?

Comment: @TruePS You aren't reading a random file. You are reading an `ObjectInputStream.` If something went wrong writing the file between writing the count and writing the last object, there will be fewer objects in the file than indicated by the count. You cannot rule this out. Disk errors and process interruptions do happen.

Comment: @TruePS, your sample looked like you'd know, if not I think you'll need to expect and handle the exception, also available() is not useful as on the stream it is documented to only return the number of bytes that can be read without blocking, not the overall number of bytes left to read.

Comment: @centic yeah available is not an alternative man.I guess I have to use try and catch block then.Could you plz take a look at this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659969/paramvalues-not-working-in-jstl-and-throwing-an-exception

Comment: @EJP yeah I also read your comments on another article regarding EOF exception.With reputaion points you are having I don't think you can be wrong in any case.So Now I believe that I have to use try and catch block.Also if you could plz take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659969/paramvalues-not-working-in-jstl-and-throwing-an-exception.

Comment: Of course I can be wrong, but I'm not wrong about this ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should close `ObjectOutputStream`in `ObjectStream` class.

```
oos.writeObject(e);
oos.writeObject(e1);
oos.writeObject(e2);

oos.close();
```

In the **MainClass** you can use a *try-finally* block to close the inputstream.

```
try
{   
  InputStream is=new java.io.FileInputStream(f);
  java.io.ObjectInputStream ois=new java.io.ObjectInputStream(is);    

    // READ logic here   
}
finally
{    
 ois.close();
 is.close();  
}
```

Comment: No it gives stream closed error because I am reading 3 objects in loop.

Comment: @TruePS No it doesn't, unless you put the close into the read loop, which isn't what he suggests here. He is certainly correct to say you should close the stream when you've finished writing it, but it doesn't resolve your actual question.

Comment: @EJP I haven't finished reading the stream so How can I close the stream before reading the whole stream.If I wanna read 100 objects then if I close the stream in the loop.How would I be able to read other 99 objects.

Comment: @TruePS you should close the *outputstream* when it finishes writing into the file. It has nothing to do with reading.

Comment: @TruePS I'll say it again. Nobody has suggested you close the stream in the read loop. Obviously you can't close the stream in the read loop. Don't close the stream in the read loop. Please read what's written here more carefully.

Comment: @r3ap3r Ok my bad I just got a little confused.I closed the stream while writing the file.But still while reading it gives EOF exception.

Comment: @TruePS It will always give `EOFException.` You have to catch it. Just accept it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You really should flush and close the object output stream in "first file".
2. You only need to close 'ois' in "third file".  The other stream is automatically closed for you.
3. If you know how many objects you're going to write, change "first file" to write the number of objects following first, then change "third file" to read that number and only read that many objects.  That way, you never get the EOF exception, because you stop reading when you've read the last object.

As EJP pointed out, you still have to catch the EOFException, because the file you're reading might be damaged.

In First File:

```
...
oos.writeInt(3);
oos.writeObject(e);
...
```

In Third File:

```
...
try {
  int numObjects = ois.readInt();
  for( int a = 0; a < numObjects; ++a ) {
      ...
  }
} catch( EOFException e ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You will 'never get the `EOFException`' unless something went wrong writing the file, which you cannot rule out in the real world, so you *will* get it, so you have to defensively code against it.

Comment: Quite correct, you still need to trap the EOF Exception, but now it's truly an exception case, instead of an abuse.

Comment: I'm not interested in discussing views on exception handling. I'm only interested in discussing how to use this API which is already designed.

Comment: @EdwinW After flushing and closing the output Stream in first file it still gives EOF exception.Secondly if let's say I wanna read a random file so How could I know in advance how many objects I have to read.

Comment: I did say "if you know how many"...  As a hacky alternative, I suppose you might try checking 'available()' to see if there's data still available to read.  It's ugly though...

Comment: @EdwinW I hate to use try and catch block except in situations where I am bound to use it.I guess this is the situation where I am bound to use it.Thanks for your support man can you plz also have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659969/paramvalues-not-working-in-jstl-and-throwing-an-exception